# Is there a web application that allows tandem drawing/painting?

Tags: webapp-rec

My daughter and I like to have **Google Doc Drawings** up on **two** computers in two different rooms and we draw shapes and write **together** in real time, which is really fun.

However, we have WACOM Pens and **she wants to color as well** which you can't do in Google Drawings (you can only place shapes and then fill them in with the bucket tool), but she wants to **draw and paint with the pen** like you can in the applications **Photoshop**, **Flash** and **MSPaint** or in the single-user webapp http://sketchswap.com.

**Does anyone know of an online painting/drawing application that allows two people to paint/draw on one canvas at the same time?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always liked [FlockDraw](http://flockdraw.com/). Others:

- http://www.imaginationcubed.com/
- http://dabbleboard.com/
- http://www.scribblar.com/

I'm sure more are available. Hope this helps.

Comment: FlockDraw is exactly what we were looking for, note you don't have to sign in with Facebook as it seems to indicate (just click cancel, two people can still share the drawing), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well... not sure if this gives you a good solution, but with the Web version of Microsoft's Office apps, you can collaborate. Perhaps you can draw at the same time in OneNote. If you have a Live.com account, you can try it by creating a new Office doc in SkyDrive.

If you ever have a multi-person activity in the same room, you can try out [Microsoft Mouse Mischief](http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-mischief/). It's an add-on to PowerPoint that lets users control mice simultaneously. Mainly targeted toward the classroom.

Answer (score -1):

[Awwapp.com](https://awwapp.com/) is a multi-user simple web whiteboard shared via url.